# Is it possible to sync Outlook with Sharepoint calendars?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, mobile

Is it possible to integrate a Sharepoint team calendar with Outlook? If not, what are other options are out there for a team site to share events, files, and a newsfeed that will also work with mobile?

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting a clear answer on this topic. I'm using Sharepoint Online.

Comment: Yes.Open sharepoint calendar and in the ribbon click Connect to outlook,

Comment: That option is not clickable for me. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: There are many possible  reasons for this.Try to disable minimal download strategy feature.

Comment: Yes, I've done a lot of research - minimal download is disabled and I've gone through all the troubleshooting steps that I could google online. It's still not an option.

Comment: Which ie 32bit or 64 bit and which version ?

Comment: Honestly, I can't even connect to my team site through Internet Explorer. I'm on a Mac so I had downloaded VirtualBox and run Windows 7 with IE 10. I get constant issues that are also impossible to resolve.

Usually I just work on the site through Google Chrome through OS X which I know can't be ideal since it's a Microsoft product.

Comment: Hi, ok I solved it myself. I have the option to connect to Outlook through Google Chrome in my VirtualBox instance of Windows 7.

Comment: Great !  For working in IE you go to Internet Explorer Options - Security tab - click on Internet zone and uncheck Enhanced Protected Mode. After that refresh the page .

Comment: Please put it as an answer and tick mark it to close the question.

Comment: Sorry, thank you! It is my first time using this website...

Answer (score 1):

I have the option to connect to Outlook through Google Chrome in my VirtualBox instance of Windows 7.

Edit: The option to click is there but it doesn't do anything.